# What does "Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch" mean?

Tags: reboot, rfkill

For the last few days, the following shows up in Syslog during reboot:

```
Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch
```

What does this mean?

Comment: can you add results of `inxi -Fxzc0` into the question?  This reads like faulty hardware